# XSLT match for XML element translation

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, soap

I have XML code that I need to translate via XSLT (prepend and append namespace values on certain elements), which seems to work fine in most cases. However, I'm running into a problem with the code below:

XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<PatientLookupResponse xmlns="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.Patient">
<PatientLookupResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Patients>
<Addresses>
</Addresses>
<HistoricalIDs/>
</Patients>
</PatientLookupResult>
</PatientLookupResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

XLST:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.External">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="HistoricalIDs">
    <HistoricalIDs xmlns:a="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.External">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </HistoricalIDs>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="HistoricalIDs/IDType">
    <a:IDType>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </a:IDType>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="HistoricalIDs/IDType/ID">
    <a:ID>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </a:ID>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="HistoricalIDs/IDType/Type">
    <a:Type>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </a:Type>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
  <PatientLookupResponse xmlns="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.Patient">
     <PatientLookupResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Patients>
           <Addresses>
           </Addresses>
           <HistoricalIDs/>
        </Patients>
     </PatientLookupResult>
  </PatientLookupResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need to have the resulting XML return `<HistoricalIDs xmlns:a="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.External"/>`. The problem is that it leaves that element the same as in the original message. The translation does work when `<PatientLookupResponse xmlns="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.Patient">` and `</PatientLookupResponse>` are not in the original message. However, when that element is there, the translation does not take place. How can I get the correct translation with the current original message?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the `PatientLookupResponse`...

```
<PatientLookupResponse xmlns="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.Patient">
```

This has a default namespace declared on it, which means that the `PatientLookupResponse` element, and all descendant nodes (unless overridden) belong to that namespace. This means `HistoricalIDs` is also part of that namespace, and a node belong to a namespace is not the same as a node with the same name that doesn't belong to the namespace.

The solution is to declare the namespace in your XSLT, with a prefix of your choice:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:a="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.External"
    xmlns:p="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.Patient"
```

Then use that namespace prefix to match the nodes in that namespace

```
<xsl:template match="p:HistoricalIDs">
```

However, you might find when you do this, that the `HistoricalIDs` gets output like so:

```
<HistoricalIDs xmlns="" xmlns:a="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.External"/>
```

This is because you are creating a new `HistoricalIDs` element in your output, one that has no namespace. So, you could either use the namespace prefix in creating the output too:

```
<xsl:template match="p:HistoricalIDs">
    <p:HistoricalIDs xmlns:a="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.External">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </p:HistoricalIDs>
</xsl:template>
```

Or you could declare a default namespace in your XSLT too, which will apply to any elements you output with no prefix

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:a="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.External"
    xmlns:p="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.Patient"
    exclude-result-prefixes="p">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p:HistoricalIDs" xmlns="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.Patient">
    <HistoricalIDs xmlns:a="urn:Epic-com:EMPI.2012.Services.External">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </HistoricalIDs>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p:HistoricalIDs/p:IDType">
    <a:IDType>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </a:IDType>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p:HistoricalIDs/p:IDType/p:ID">
    <a:ID>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </a:ID>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p:HistoricalIDs/p:IDType/p:Type">
    <a:Type>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </a:Type>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```